# NancyFX Functional Testing with Autofac

Tags: autofac, functional-testing, nancy

I've implemented Autofac as my DI Container of choice in place of TinyIoC which is the default in Nancy.

I've got the API working, and I can easily connect to it via the browser, however my functional tests are failing. They're failing because I'm trying to use the Nancy [Browser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Testing/) to setup the tests, but it requires the TinyIoC Container (which isn't there).

Is there a simple way to extend/override the Browser to take an Autofac container instead of the TinyIoC one? Alternatively (and probably better), is there a Nancy.Testing Browser that "can" use a different container?

> SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : Something went wrong when
>   trying to satisfy one of the dependencies during composition, make
>   sure that you've registered all new dependencies in the container and
>   inspect the innerexception for more details.   ---->
>   Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException : Unable to resolve type:
>   Nancy.NancyEngine   ----> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException :
>   Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher   ---->
>   Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException : Unable to resolve type:
>   Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteResolver   ---->
>   Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException : Unable to resolve type:
>   Nancy.Routing.RouteCache   ---->
>   Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException : Unable to resolve type:
>   TimeTracker.Web.Api.UserModule   ---->
>   Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException : Unable to resolve type:
>   TimeTracker.Services.IUserService

As you can see, TinyIoC Cannot resolve IUserService.

> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException : Unable to resolve type:
>   TimeTracker.Services.IUserService

This is because I'm not registering ANYTHING with TinyIoC... Instead I'm registering it with Autofac.

```
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _browser = new Browser(with =>
            {
                with.Module<UserModule>();

                // forcing me to use TinyIoCContainer
                with.ApplicationStartup((x, pipelines) =>
                    {
                        var container = BootStrapper.ConfigureContainer(new ContainerBuilder().Build());

                        var userValidator = container.Resolve<IUserValidator>();
                        var basicAuthConfig = new BasicAuthenticationConfiguration(userValidator, "TimeTra.ca");
                        pipelines.EnableBasicAuthentication(basicAuthConfig);

                        pipelines.OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(
                            (context, exception) => CustomErrorResponse.FromException(exception));

                        // Setup a clean database
                        var migrationRunner = new MigrationRunner(container.Resolve<IDbProvider>());
                        migrationRunner.DropDatabase();
                        migrationRunner.CreateDatabase();

                        BootStrapper.RunMigrations(container);
                        SeedData.SetupFixtureDataInDatabase(container.Resolve<IServiceLocator>());
                    });
            });
    }

    private Browser _browser;
```

Comment: It seems to be IUserService that is missing. Have you tried suplying IUserService by way of with.Dependency?

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal unfortunately that has nothing to do with it. Its the fact that I'm not using the default container that Nancy wants.

Comment: How do you know that? -I does not seem that way to me, from what you posted in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your Autofac bootstrapper when testing you need to use the `Browser(INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper, Action<BrowserContext> defaults = null)` constructor and explicitly specify an instance of your bootstrapper.

The problem with this approach is that it will be hard for you to "replace" components for testing purposes, i.e. using mocks etc., that's why the `ConfigurableBootstrapper` exists. I'm also not quite sure how it will affect module discovery. With the `ConfigurableBootstrapper` you explicitly say which modules you want to use along with the other services.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was over complicating it. `var bootstrapper = new BootStrapper(); _browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);`

Comment: ok, so after testing this approach, my API is always throwing 404. I haven't dug into the debugger to see why...